# Show function $f(x)=\frac{r^2 \cdot a}{a^2+x^2}$ is strictly decreasing

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I want to show, that

$$f(x)=\frac{r^2 \cdot a}{a^2+x^2}$$

with $x,a,r \in \mathbb{R}$ is strictly decreasing for $x>0$

A function is called strictly decreasing, if $x_1<x_2 \Rightarrow f(x_1)>f(x_2)$.

Perhaps someone can give me a hint how to start.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: As a function of $x$, it is **increasing** up to $x=0$, and then decreasing.

Comment: Exactly, that is why it is increasing then decreasing, because $f(-x) = f(x)$.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to add $x>0$.

Comment: Maybe the sign of $a$ also needs to be specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need $a > 0$ for this to be true. What you want to show is that if $0 < x_1 < x_2$ that you have
$$\frac{r^2  a}{a^2 + x_2^2} < \frac{r^2  a}{a^2 + x_1^2} $$
Putting everything on one side this is the same as showing
$$\frac{r^2  a}{a^2 + x_2^2} - \frac{r^2  a}{a^2 + x_1^2} < 0$$
Writing with a single denominator this becomes
$$r^2a{x_1^2 - x_2^2 \over (a^2 + x_1^2)(a^2 + x_2^2)} < 0$$
This is true since the denominator is positive, and the numerator is negative since $0 < x_1 < x_2$.

---

Note also that if you have derivatives, you can just take the derivative to get
$$f'(x) = -r^2a{2x \over (x^2 + a^2)^2}$$
Since this is negative for $x > 0$ the function is decreasing.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(x)=\dfrac{r^2 \cdot a}{a^2+x^2}$ is strictly decreasing for $x>0$ and $a>0.$
For $x_1>0,\;\; x_2>0$ 
$$x_1<x_2 \Rightarrow x_1^2<x_2^2 \Rightarrow {a^2+x_1^2}<a^2+x_2^2 \Rightarrow  \frac{1}{a^2+x_1^2}>\frac{1}{a^2+x_2^2}$$
Then for $a>0$ $$\frac{r^2 a}{a^2+x_1^2}>\frac{r^2 a}{a^2+x_2^2} \ .$$

Answer (score 1):

The constants in the numerator and denominator are irrelevant, you want to show that $1/(a + x^2)$ is decreasing when for $x > 0$ when $a \geq 0$. For this just take the derivative.